# Simultaneous reading/writing using manual SQL and c# program

Tags: c#, sql, networking

I have an SQL server for storing various settings for a c# program. The program periodically checks these settings. If I would manually change the settings with a query, and the program tries to read them simultaneously, will this cause an error? In other words, does SQL "multitask"? It doesn't matter if the manual settings change is delayed until the next check by the program, as long as nothing crashes.

Comment: You can always have a second connection, then it can easily

Comment: Depends if you use transactions or not. You can set transaction isolation level to READ UNCOMMITED - this way one process will have exclusive rights to write to the table while others can read the "dirty" data.

Answer (score 0):

Allmost all RDBMS (including Oracle, MS SQL, Interbase etc.) are as you've put it "multitask". Moreover, RDMS are specially designed to work in such a mode (see ACID for detailes)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

The only trick is that you should not *share* `Connection` between different task, threads, ect:

```
  Action action1 = () => {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
      conn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand()) {
        q.Connection = conn;
        q.CommandText = "update MyTable set x = 123 where y = 789";

        q.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  };

  Action action2 = () => {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
      conn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand()) {
        q.Connection = conn;
        q.CommandText = "delete from MyTable where y = 456";

        q.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  };

  // Let's call both actions in parallel (simultaneously)
  Parallel.Invoke(action1, action2);
```